# Can't delete SQLite column with (Begin Transaction) method

Tags: java, android, sqlite

In the Android Studio SQLite database, I have a table "title" With two columns (name, id) I want to delete the id column, I used the Transaction Method but it doesn't work.
After copying the name column to a new table, I want that the new table should have itself id column.

```
     try {
            SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.openOrCreateDatabase("db", MODE_PRIVATE, null);

    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("BEGIN TRANSACTION");
            sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t1(name VARCHAR)");
            sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("INSERT INTO t1 SELECT name FROM title");
            sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE title");
            sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("CREATE TABLE title (name VARCHAR, id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY)");
            sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("INSERT INTO title SELECT name FROM t1");
            sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE t1");
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("COMMIT");

           } catch (Exception e) {

        }
```

And I also tried this

```
 try {
            SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.openOrCreateDatabase("db", MODE_PRIVATE, null);

    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("BEGIN TRANSACTION");
            sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t1(name VARCHAR,id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY)");
            sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("INSERT INTO t1 SELECT name FROM title");
            sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE title");
            sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("CREATE TABLE title (name VARCHAR, id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY)");
            sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("INSERT INTO title SELECT name,id FROM t1");
            sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE t1");
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("COMMIT");

           } catch (Exception e) {

        }
```

Comment: There is some error message?

Comment: No nothing happens, just when i close the app and open it again it doesn't show database records because it locks the database

Comment: what it the `Exception e` you are getting? what does `printStackTrace()` show on the logcat?

Comment: do you know why you are using `try {} catch {}` form? do you know what `catch (Exception e)` is used for?

Comment: Yes i do, if you can't answer my question please don't ask usless questions.

Comment: useless questions? do you think that if your code throws an exception it is useless? why dont you call `e.printStackTrace()` inside `catch`? why? did you see my first comment here? do you want to learn anything or not?

Comment: I didn't get any error in catch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is due to the trapped exception :-

```
SQLiteException: table title has 2 columns but 1 values were supplied (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: INSERT INTO title SELECT name FROM t1
```

i.e you are not providing a value for the **id** column.

Change to use

```
sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("INSERT INTO title SELECT name, null FROM t1");
```

or

```
sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("INSERT INTO title (name) SELECT name FROM t1");
```

Comment: @HabibMhamadi P.S. It's generally better to not wrap SQLite actions in try/catch.